# How can I use a vector wrapper class when enclosed in another vector?

Tags: c++, vector, wrapper, stdvector

Consider a free function from a third part library that expects a `std::vector` as argument: `void foo( std::vector<sometype>& );`

Now, I write a wrapper around this type so I can add member functions. To be able to use `foo()` with that type, I add an access function.

```
class Wrapper
{
   private:
      std::vector<sometype> _data;
   public:
       std::vector<sometype>& data() { return _data; }
       const std::vector<sometype>& data() const { return _data; }
       //... other stuff
};
```

This way, I can still use `foo()`:

```
Wrapper a;
foo( a.data() );
```

But now consider another function, that expects a vector of vectors of `sometype` (**edit: and that adds elements into that vector**) :

```
void bar( std::vector<std::vector<sometype>>& );
```

But the datatype I have is `std::vector<Wrapper> vec;`

**Is there any way to use my wrapper type to call `bar()` ?**
What I want to do is this:

```
 std::vector<Wrapper> vec;
 bar( ??? );
```

The point I want to avoid is first call `bar()` with the required type, and then having to copy one by one the elements into my `vector<Wrapper>`.

At first, I'd say "No", but maybe there is some smart solution ?

**Edit2**: to give an example, consider the following toy implementation for `bar()` with an `int` root datatype:

```
void bar( std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vv )
{
   std::vector<int> v1 = { 1,2,3 };
   std::vector<int> v2 = { 4,5,6 };
   vv.push_back(v1);
   vv.push_back(v2);
}
```

Comment: the third party library is probably not changeable, otherwise I'd suggest it should accept iterators instead of a vector

Comment: Exactly, you got the point, can't change it.

Comment: Two questions: 1 - do you also need to delete items from those vectors? 2 - Does bar add/delete elements to the vector of vectors? If the answer to both is 'no', [this is a possible solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fdcebcbc58065d1)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. Q2: yes,`bar()` actually fills the vector with elements (thus the lack of `const`). These will be later processed. Anyway, I'll check your code and try to understand it, thanks for your time ;-). Maybe you can post as an answer, even if it doesn't entirely answer the problem ?

Comment: @kebs done, although I'd prefer something smarter myself. If nothing else comes up it might work though.

Answer (score 3):

*[Edited after new comments requiring elements added in the bar function]*
A possible solution would be to keep a `std::vector<std::vector<sometype>>` for the function to use and just operate on a `VectorAccessor` object *referring* to the real vectors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct sometype {
    int value;
    sometype(int v) : value(v) {}
};

void bar(std::vector<std::vector<sometype>>& par) {

    std::cout << "bar() - Before adding new elements:" << std::endl;
    for (auto& subvec : par) {
        std::cout << "Subvector: {";
        for (auto& sometypeItem : subvec) {
            std::cout << sometypeItem.value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "};" << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<sometype> newItem = {32, 33};
    par.emplace_back(newItem);

}

class VectorAccessor {
    std::vector<std::vector<sometype>>& m_vec;
public:
    VectorAccessor(std::vector<std::vector<sometype>>& v) : m_vec(v) {}

    template<typename V>
    void addVector(V&& vec) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<V>::type, 
            std::vector<sometype>>::value, "Not the right type");
        m_vec.emplace_back(std::forward<V>(vec));
    }

    std::vector<sometype> accessVector(size_t index) {
        return m_vec[index];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    std::vector<std::vector<sometype>> vec;
    VectorAccessor vAcc(vec);


    // Add an element through the vector accessor
    std::vector<sometype> firstVector = {42};
    firstVector.emplace_back(52);
    vAcc.addVector(firstVector);

    // Call bar and add a few elements
    bar(vec);

    // Now access stuff with the usual wrapper
    std::cout << "Elements added by bar:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Subvector: {";
    for (auto& sometypeItem : vAcc.accessVector(1)) {
        std::cout << sometypeItem.value << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "};" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97bc9da545a67546)</kbd>

Comment: I just tried, but its always the same problem: adding elements to the vector in the `bar()` function does not add them in `internalVec`... (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b53331252ca56ec1)

Comment: @kebs Edited, that requirement was added with the comments and the previous answer dated before it

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, calling a function taking a `vector<vector<something>` won't work with a `vector<Wrapper>`, because their type is different, and the compiler explicitely expects the former.

I don't think there is any way this form of type substitution could work in C++.

### Workaround

There's a workaround to everyhting : you could use conversions in your own code to let the magic happen.

Let me explain.

If the function you intend to use takes a `vector<vector<something>>`, in C++, you **basically *have to* give it a `vector<vector<something>>`**. So you can't create your vector as a `vector<Wrapper>` and avoid converting it to a `vector<vector<something>>`.

On the other hand, you can

1. use a `vector<vector<something>` in which you will push instances of `Wrapper` (using an implicit conversion).
2. if you need `Wrapper` functionnality, you can convert your `vector<something>` using a conversion constructor.

Let's take that example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//Templated class wrapper. It does not have to be templated though.
template<typename T>
class Wrapper{

private:
    
    //Here is our inner vector.
    vector<T> vect;

public:

    //here is our implicit convertion operator : 
    operator vector<T>& () const {return this->vect;} 

    //A function so that we can push some stuff in it
    void push(T elem){
        this->vect.push_back(elem);
    }
   
    //here is some additional functionnality in top of vector;
    void print(){
        int i = 0;
        for(i=0;i<this->vect.size();i++){
            cout << vect[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    //this is our very simple conversion constructor
    Wrapper<T>(vector<T> vect){
        this->vect = vect;
    }

    //we still need a normal constructor
    Wrapper<T>(){}
};

//A function that takes a vector of vectors.
vector<int> concat(vector<vector<int>> vectors){
    int i = 0,j=0;
    vector<int> result;
    for(i=0;i<vectors.size();i++){
        for(j=0;j<vectors[i].size();j++){
            result.push_back(vectors[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    //Let's create an instance of Wrapper and fill it.
    Wrapper<int>ex;
    ex.push(1);
    ex.push(2);

    //And yet another one
    Wrapper<int>ex2;
    ex2.push(5);
    ex2.push(6);

    //Here we create precisely what the 'concat' function wants:
    //namely a vector<vector<int>>.
    vector<vector<int>> vectors;

    //you can push Wrappers in it, since the conversion will take place.
    vectors.push_back(ex);
    vectors.push_back(ex2);

    //this function call will be successful, since the type of
    //vectors is vector<vector<int>>
    vector<int> res = concat(vectors);

    //Now if you want to use the wrapper functionnality on any
    //vector<int>, just convert it on-demand.
    //The constructor is extra light-weight in terms of computing power
    //as you can see above.
    Wrapper<int>(res).print();
    Wrapper<int>(vectors[0]).print();
}
```

> P.S. The `push_back` function will copy the element, so if your function does modify your vector, it won't be reflected on the Wrapper, since it's a copy of its inner vector that has been modified. Using a real `vector<something>` and `push_back` would result in the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but again, 1-I can't change the function's signature, 2-the function adds elements to the vector.

Comment: Using this, you don't have to change the function signature; that's the whole point :) The signature of the `concat` function does take a vector of vectors, even if its argument was constructed using Wrappers. If the function adds elements to the inner vector, you can still call `Wrapper(...).yourFunction()` on the resulting vector, as if it had been a Wrapper all along. ;)

Comment: Your `concat()` function returns something, my `bar()` does not, so, yes, you do change the signature.

Comment: Hum, I see. But I don't think this is your problem here : when you `push_back` a value in a vector, its value is copied; which means that `vector.push_back(anything)` will create a copy of `anything` and that won't be reflected on the original. Then if you want to track the new values in the inner vector, I'm afraid you'll have to access it using the outer one since the copy is not referenced anywhere else : `bar(outerVect); Wrapper innerVect = Wrapper(outerVect[n]);`

Answer (score 1):

instead of    `std::vector<Wrapper> vec;`

use

```
std::vector< std::vector<sometype> > vec;
```

anyway, you can insert your Wrapper objects into vec

```
vec.push_back(a.data());
```

and then call  `bar(vec);`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately, `bar()` adds elements to the vector, it doesn't just process what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I came up with something that seems to work, although there could be some issues left. The idea is to wrap the vector of vectors into some global wrapper, and then the initial wrapper accessing the data inside it using pointers.

Say with the following toy `bar()` function:

```
void bar(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& par)
{
   std::vector<int> v1 = { 1,2,3 };
   par.push_back(v1);
}
```

The two wrappers:

```
struct GlobalWrapper
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> _data;

    size_t size() const { return _data.size(); }
    std::vector<int>& Get( size_t i ) { return _data[i]; }
    const std::vector<int>& Get( size_t i ) const { return _data[i]; }
};

struct Wrapper
{
    std::vector<int>* _data;

    void DoSomething() const
    {
        cout << "values: "; 
        std::copy( _data->begin(), _data->end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));        
    }
    Wrapper( std::vector<int>& value ) : _data(&value)
    {
    }
};
```

And a test program:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    GlobalWrapper gw;

    cout << "size before=" << gw.size() << endl;
    bar( gw._data );
    cout << "size after=" << gw.size() << endl;

    Wrapper w = gw.Get(0); // get first element and do something with it
    w.DoSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

One issue left: ownership of data. Probably needs some smart pointers.

Running code [is here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc168b2d43cd983f).